# How to Submit a Form on different website from WordPress plugin ShortCoder

Tags: wordpress, selenium, automation, headless

I want to make it so that, on my WordPress site, when a new user registers their account, it triggers a chain of events which registers a new user account on another unrelated site.

On my WordPress I'm using the ProfileBuilder plugin to provide the Registration Form and am using the Shortcoder plugin to insert a chunk of javascript on the same page.

My plan was to grab the Form inputs off of the DOM using javascript and then somehow send a request to the other website using the collected data. Can you please help me by either presenting a solution for this problem, naming some of the software I will need to accomplish this goal, or simply naming what it is exactly that I'm trying to do? I'm not a veteran programmer so I don't have the precise language that I need to describe my problem or what I want to accomplish in correct technical terms. Someone suggested that I use Selenium, but I want this to work regardless of the machine being used; I understand that Selenium is software installed onto your machine and I want this code to run automatically, upon Form Submission on the Wordpress site, whether my computer is on or off. Also the site to which I want to add the New User is password protected.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _username = document.getElementsByClassName('default_field_username')[0].value
  var _email = document.getElementsByClassName('default_field_email')[0].value
  var _password = document.getElementById('passw1').value
  var _repeated_password = document.getElementById('passw2').value
  var _userCredentials = {
    username: _username,
    email: _email,
    password: _password,
    repeatPassword: _repeated_password
  }

  function addUserToPruvan(_credHash){
    // POST request to other site would go here
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    addUserToPruvan(_userCredentials)
  })  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Keep going how you started.

I'd use jQuery for the POST part.

It's super simple, here's an example of what it could look like:

```
<script src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist/releases/tag/3.3.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    ...

    $.post({
      url: "api.php",
      data: _userCredentials,
    }).done(function(response) {
      ......
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      ......
    });


    ...

  });
  </script>
```

PREVIOUS ANSWER

If you're project allows it,  you can share the user_table between multiple WordPress installs.

You'd need to put both WordPress databases in one SQL database, each with a different table prefix.

```
 //wp-config.php number 1
$table_prefix  = 'first_';
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', $table_prefix . 'users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', $table_prefix . 'usermeta' );

//wp-config.php number 2
$table_prefix  = 'second_';
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'first_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'first_usermeta' );
```

You need to make sure each user has copies of the caps and level, like so:
[image]

```
// automatically copy caps and level across from 1 to 2
// repeat to do 2 to 1
function ksu_save_role( $user_id, $role ) {
    $prefix_1 = 'first_';
    $prefix_2 = 'second_';

    $caps = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_1 . 'capabilities', true );
    $level = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_1 . 'user_level', true );

    if ( $caps )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_2 . 'capabilities', $caps );

    if ( $level )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_2 . 'user_level', $level );
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'ksu_save_role', 10, 2 );
```

Here is where I learned about this:
https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/

Comment: the second site is a non-WordPress site.